# How to use MassTransit test harness to test Consumer with constructor dependency injection?

Tags: xunit, masstransit

I have some message consumers that take dependencies through the constructor, and I would like to cover them in unit tests. Does MassTransit's test harness provide a way to register consumers with constructor parameters?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can specify a factory method, or a consumer factory, when creating a consumer test harness.

```
harness.Consumer<T>(() => new T());
```

You can find the three standard extension methods in the code:

https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/develop/src/MassTransit/Testing/ConsumerTestHarnessExtensions.cs#L35

UPDATE:
MassTransit now has [container support for the test harness](https://masstransit-project.com/releases/v7.0.4.html#containers)