# How to use MassTransit test harness to test sagas with Activities (Automatonymous.Binders.EventActivityBinder) with constructor dependency injection?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, masstransit, saga

To keep saga code simple I created activities that are executed when a saga event is triggered. Now I'd like to create tests for the saga using MT's test harness. I also need to mock dependencies from these activities. How can this be done in MT 7.0.2?

This question is similar to the one found here:
[How to use MassTransit test harness to test Consumer with constructor dependency injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55169197/how-to-use-masstransit-test-harness-to-test-consumer-with-constructor-dependency)

Below is some pseudo code to exemplify my use case:

```
public class SomeSaga : MassTransitStateMachine<SomeSagaState>
{
    public Event<InitializeCommand> Initialize { get; set; }
    
    public State Initialized { get; set; }

    public SomeSaga()
    {
        InstanceState(x => x.CurrentState);
        Event(() => Initialize, e => { e.CorrelateById(c => c.Message.CorrelationId); });

        Initially(
            When(Initialize)
                .Activity(x => x.OfType<InitializeActivity>())
                .TransitionTo(Initialized));
    }
}

public class InitializeActivity : Activity<SomeSagaState, InitializeCommand>
{
    private readonly ISomeDependency _dep;

    public InitializeActivity(ISomeDependency dep)
    {
        _dep = dep ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(dep));
    }
    
    public async Task Execute(...)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need at least v7.0.4 of MassTransit, though I'd suggest using the latest version. Container support for the InMemoryTestHarness [was added](https://masstransit-project.com/releases/v7.0.4.html#containers) in that version.

There are also extensive examples of how to use it in [Sample-Library](https://github.com/MassTransit/Sample-Library).

Comment: Thanks, @Chris Patterson!